# Reading a particular row in csv file with Python

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

How to read string row in python?

I got a football csv file.

https://www.football-data.co.uk/mmz4281/1920/F1.csv
I would like to retrieve all the lines where there is the PS Germain.

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv('F1.csv')
dh = df[['Date','HomeTeam','AwayTeam','FTHG','FTAG']]
dh.head()
```

Comment: What is the "PS Germain"?  Is that a team name?

Comment: Yeah, it's a French soccer team.

Comment: Still learning myself, but is it in the data?

Comment: Yes it is a data in the Hometeam column.

Comment: @maceobs `dh[dh['HomeTeam'] == 'PS Germain']`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

'Paris SG' HomeTeam **or** AwayTeam:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv('F1.csv')
dh = df[['Date','HomeTeam','AwayTeam','FTHG','FTAG']]

index_list = dh[(dh['HomeTeam'] == 'Paris SG') | (dh['AwayTeam'] == 'Paris SG')].index.tolist()
dh_final = dh.iloc[index_list]
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to select rows from your Pandas DataFrame.
You can use the following logic to select rows from Pandas DataFrame based on specific conditions:

*df.loc[df['column name'] condition]*

In pratice that means:

```
result = df.loc[df['HomeTeam'] == 'PS Germain']
```

You're getting the result with:

```
print(result)
```

Of course you can use more conditions and combine them.

Answer (score 0):

Filtering where `Paris SG` is in the `HomeTeam` column:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('https://www.football-data.co.uk/mmz4281/1920/F1.csv')
df = df[df['HomeTeam'] == 'Paris SG']
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the below sample:

```
for ind in df.index:
  if(df['HomeTeam'][ind]=='PS Germain'):
    #Do the needfull
```

Comment: I don't think it is optimal solution. Could you elaborate your answer?